# I'm getting the error Exception: The parameters (number[]) don't match the method signature for SpreadsheetApp.Range.setValues, does anyone know why?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-drive-api

```
do { //Get all the pages of comments in case the doc has more than 100
    callArguments['pageToken'] = pageToken;
    //This is where the magic happens!
    docComments = Drive.Comments.list(fileId,callArguments);
    //I've created a "getCommentsInfo" to organize the relevant info in an array
    info = info.concat((docComments.items));
    if (docComments.items && docComments.items.length > 0) {
      for (var i = 0; i < docComments.items.length; i++) {
        var comment = docComments.items[i]; 
        // add comment and highlight to array's first element 
        info.unshift([comment.content]);
        pageToken = docComments.nextPageToken;
      }
    }
commentsheet.getRange("A1:A"+ info.length).setValues(info);
```

I have a 2D array which is the variable info. Here is a cutoff of what it looks like:

Logging output too large. Truncating output. [[projected weight], [projected weight], [projected weight], [projected weight], [projected weight], [projected weight], [projected weight], [pre-gym weight - 150.4 bf% - 6.7
post-gym weight -150.2 bf% - 7.8], [pre-cardio weight 149.4 bf% -7.1], [225 lbs], [225], [275], [295], [225], [185], [185], [185], [bodyweight], [bodyweight], [35], [35], [150], [170], [190], [185], [185], [185], [185], [205], [205], [215], [225], [7.5], [9], [10.5], [95], [95], [95], [bodyweight], [25], [25], [70], [70], [70], [80], [80], [80], [100], [115], [115], [3 45s], [3 45s + 1 25], [4 45s], [75], [75], [75], [95], [95], [95], [70], [90], [90], [135], [185], [205], [225], [135], [155], [175], [175], [35], [35], [35], [35], [25], [25], [25], [17.5], [22.5], [22.5], [32.5], [42.5], [42.5], [7.5], [9], [10.5], [135], [155], [155], [175], [35], [35], [35], [35], [130], [130], [130], [70], [70], [70], [70], [115], [115], [115], [115], [3 45s], [3 45s + 1 25], [3 45s + 1 25], [4 45s], [70], [70],

I am trying to add this 2D array of comments to the commentsheet, which is 4762 rows and 1 column. Does anyone know where I messing up? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Removing the

```
info = info.concat((docComments.items));
```

fixed the issue I have was having.